# Grab last status in cell with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a SQL query that isn't quite what I want. Currently I'm grabbing customers with `s.status` = cancelled but that isn't quite right.

`s.status` can contain info like "active, cancelled, active, paused, cancelled"... I.e several different states.

How can I grab only customers where the very last status is "cancelled"?

```
SELECT s.customer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.status) AS status_list, GROUP_CONCAT(s.created) AS created_date_list, GROUP_CONCAT(s.start_date) AS start_date_list, max(c.customer_name), max(c.customer_email), max(c.updated_profile), max(p.newsletter_sub)
from imp_subscriptions s 
LEFT JOIN imp_customerdata c ON c.user_id = s.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN imp_communication_preference p ON c.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE s.status = 'cancelled' AND p.newsletter_sub = 'yes'
GROUP BY customer_id
```

[image]

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  (as  tabular text) and the expceted  result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

want to check the last 9 character are cancelled?  do it like this:

```
where lower(right(rtrim(s.status),9)) = 'cancelled'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `like`:

```
s.status like '%cancelled'
```

Or, if you really want:

```
right(s.status, 9) = 'cancelled'
```